# How to allow application to have write access to a specific SharePoint folder?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, permissions, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-app-registration

I want to upload a file into a folder in the SharePoint document library using PowerShell.

For this, I am using the following link to setup the app: `/_layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx`

Followed by registration: `/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx`

XML for permissions is:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
   <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web/list" Right="Write" ></AppPermissionRequest>
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

Reference for xml permissions: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/add-in-permissions-in-sharepoint

Then it asks me to choose the list/library and I select `Documents`. This gives it `write` access to the entire document library. Is there any way to allow access to only 1 particular folder in the document library?

[image]

Comment: Just a note, Microsoft has hinted that SharePoint Add-ins will be deprecated in the not too distant future. This means that the Add-in permission model, which is what you are using when you register an app with AppRegNew.aspx, would be deprecated in the not too distant future as well. The suggestion is to register applications with Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) instead. Just note that the permission scopes currently available in Azure AD are less granular that those available with the Add-in permission model. Hopefully this discrepancy will be addressed in the future.

Comment: The Azure AD approach doesn't allow me to choose a specific site or document library?

Comment: Azure AD approach will allow you to choose specific site using `Sites.Selected` permissions. It will not allow document library or folder level permissions.

Comment: Is using graph api an option?

Comment: @variable Microsoft Graph API is an option, but it doesn't have granular permission options either. The most granular is the site level (`Sites.Selected`), not the list/library level and definitely not the folder level.

Comment: And any idea whether the client secret created using Sharepoint app reg can be set to not expire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot allow access to only 1 particular folder in the document library using app registrations.

You can only use below permission scope levels:

1. Tenant
2. Site Collection
3. Site (web)
4. List/Library

**Documentation**: [Types of add-in permissions and permission scopes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/add-in-permissions-in-sharepoint#types-of-add-in-permissions-and-permission-scopes)

Comment: What is the alternative to allows access to only 1 folder?

Comment: More information can be found here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/add-in-permissions-in-sharepoint#types-of-add-in-permissions-and-permission-scopes

Comment: It is not possible to grant access to only one folder using app registrations, no workaround for this using app registrations.

Comment: Any other technique that you recommend to achieve this?

Comment: App registrations (both SharePoint or Azure AD) don't have folder level granular permissions. Any particular reason you are using app registration & not service account or administrator account to run powershell?

Answer (score 1):

No. The SharePoint Add-in permission model does not support that level of granularity. Access to the list or library is as granular as you can get.